# How do you say "What do you mean?" in Latin?

Tags: word-request

I know "to mean" is usually translated as "significare", however, I feel like that in the question "What do you mean?" it means something completely different. In Croatian we say "Kako to misliš?" which literally translates to "How do you think it?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*quid istuc est* (lit. "what is that thing you mentioned"), possibly. I am drawing it from [Paul Nixon's translation of Plautus's works](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/16564/16564-h/16564-h.htm).

Many constructions in a variety of contexts in this translation are translated as "what do you mean". They are all *qui*-constructions, and pick up a variety of interesting inflections and adverbs depending on what exactly is being referred to. I suspect the general answer will depend heavily on context.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the context. One option is to ask 'Quid dicere vis?' (What do you want to say?)

You would use the verb 'significare' as in 'Quid hoc significat?' (What does this mean?)